# modifying required for form elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'd like to set more conditions before submitting a form, using the html 'required' property for a form field. Is there a way I can manually intercept/change the conditions it checks? In my case I'd like to require a field to be a value from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat lengthy process but very useful.
You can have a `on change` event on any `input` tag in the `form`,

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)} name="fname"/>


handleUserInput(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value}, 
            () => { this.validateField(name, value) });
} 



validateField(fieldName, value) {
    let fnameValid = this.state.fnameValid;
    switch(fieldName) {
      case 'fname':
         fnameValid = value!=="" && /^([a-zA-Z]+)$/.test(value) && value.length >= 2; //here you can check as many condition as you want using `&&` operator.
        break;
      case 'more input name here':
       ... // More input validation
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

[Ref](https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-do-simple-form-validation-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using React (and therefore JSX) you can do it this way:

```
const myComp = (props) => {
  const [isRequired, setIsRequired] = useState(true);

  if(your logic for when isRequired should be true here){
    setIsRequired(false)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form required={isRequired} />
    </div>
)
}
```

You can check any data you want checked in that `if`, have multiple ifs, multiple checks, an array of checks, whatever you want. I made it default required true, but you can do it as you wish. Even having logic for the default `isRequired` value to be something specific.

I'm using the `required` html property here, but you could also intercept the `onSubmit` form event and do your own checks there and explain the user what it's left to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook a onsubmit event

```
<form onsubmit="return checkYourCondition()">
<form>


function checkYourCondition(){
    //return true or false depending on your condition 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate an RegEx containing all the array values and set the pattern attribute of the `input` to this RegEx.

With this solution you will have the default behavior the browser has if a required input is not valid. (e.g. highlighting the input, informing the user, ...)